# How to solve time constraint with coding challenge

Tags: c#, .net, testing, puzzle

I was doing a coding test (for practice) that went something like this:

Input is a string with |'s and *'s.
E.g. `**|*|*|**|***`

Implement the function:
`List<int> countItems(string line, List<int> startLocations, List<int> endLocations)`

Count the number of `*` characters that are between an opening and closing pair of `|` characters.

Where the 2 locations are arrays with the start and end locations (indices) to consider withing the string **line**.

For example if line = `*|*|*` and startLocations = [1] and endLocations = [3] it means
I need to check the substring `*|*`.
And since there is only 1 pipe, the result is zero.
The location values seemed to be 1-based and not 0-based for some reason.

If the range was 1 and 5, for example, the result would be 1 because there is only 1 * between pipes.

The code I came up with that did manage to solve about half the test cases is as follows:

```cs
List<int> countItems(string line, List<int> startLocations, List<int> endLocations)
{
    var results = new List<int>();
    
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) || startLocations.Count == 0)
    {
        return results;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < startLocations.Count; i++)
    {
        var startIndex = startLocations[i] - 1;
        var endIndex = endLocations[i] - 1;

        var start = false;
        var total = 0;
        var tempTotal = 0;

        for (var j = startIndex; j < endIndex; j++)
        {
            if (!start && line[j] == '|')
            {
                start = true;
                tempTotal = 0;
            }
            else if (start && line[j] == '*')
            {
                tempTotal++;
            }
            else if (line[j] == '|')
            {
                total += tempTotal;
                tempTotal = 0;
            }
        }

        if (line[endIndex] == '|')
        {
            total += tempTotal;
        }

        results.Add(total);
    }

    return results;
}
```

All the test cases either passed or failed because it ran out of time.

The error said it exceeded a time of 3 seconds.

Now I couldn't see the actual data being passed into the tests, so I'm not able to test it more.

But I suspect the solution was some kind of temporary list or dictionary so as to only iterate over the string 1 time instead of many times as in my code.

I want to learn what kind of solution to use in cases like this, but not really sure if this is a common type of question where the solution has some kind of name or common concept.

I would appreciate any obvious pointers to solving this type of question or even links to similar programming challenges where I can practice more.

Comment: I think you are looking for: NumBetween = (Total Star)- (Num to Left of Left Pipe)- (Num to Right of Right Pipe), probably with added map Position -> (Nearest Left Pipe, Nearest Right Pipe).

Comment: Note that you should figure out if "pair" refers to balanced pair or not: `*|**|***|*` for 1,10 - should result be 0,2,3, or 5?

Comment: Based on the tests that did pass, it didn't seem to be balanced pairs. Basically anything after the first pipe and before the last one

Comment: Ok, than I think my first comment should give you O(string length + number of locations) instead of  O(string length * number of locations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to redo the test and I found the answer and problem type.

This is a "plates between candles" type of problem.

I was trying to solve it myself but almost ran out of time and eventually just copy/pasted an answer I found.
This was a practice run, not an actual test or application.

This was the solution that worked... I'll be studying it to better understand it...

```
List<int> numberOfItems(string s, List<int> startIndices, List<int> endIndices)
{
    int q = startIndices.Count;
    int l = s.Length;

    for (var i = 0; i < startIndices.Count; i++)
    {
        startIndices[i]--;
        endIndices[i]--;
    }

    var ans = new List<int>();
    var prev = new int[l];
    var next = new int[l];
    var preSum = new int[l];

    int p = -1, nxt = -1;

    // calculating prev candle up to this index.
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {

        if (s[i] == '|')
        {
            p = i;
        }
        prev[i] = p;
    }
    //Calculating next candle from this index.

    for (int i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {

        if (s[i] == '|')
        {
            nxt = i;
        }
        next[i] = nxt;
    }

    int c = 0;

    // calculating the number of stars between these indices.
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {

        if (s[i] == '*')
        {
            c++;
        }
        preSum[i] = c;
    }

    // calculating ans.
    for (int k = 0; k < q; k++)
    {

        int i = startIndices[k];
        int j = endIndices[k];

        int right = prev[j];// position of left candle.
        int left = next[i];// position of right candle.
                           //cout<<right<<left;

        if (left == -1 || right == -1 || left > right)
        {
            ans.Add(0);
        }
        else
        {
            ans.Add(preSum[right] - preSum[left]);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think the best option would be to use stack theory.
It is a variation of the parenthesis balancing problem. You can find more about it here
[Article parenthesis balancing problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/)

Comment: I don't think this approach is applicable to this problem. I think Alexei's comment is probably the answer. To count the stars to the left and right of the first and last pipe and subtract that from the total star count. 
That way, I can count all the stars of the string only once and then use the start and end indices to only count how many to subtract, or something of that nature